# Speeding up Python S3 Copy/Delete function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, boto3

I wrote a function to cleanup old files in one of my S3 buckets. The function grabs a list of objects from the folder, checks to see if they're more than a week old, and if so moves them to another folder and deletes them from the original.

The issue is that I have millions of older files, and this lambda only processes about 6 thousand every 15 minutes. I need to dramatically speed up the runtime of the lambda to process everything in a resonable timeframe

Here's the function code

```
#This function cycles through an S3 bucket and moves any legacy files to a processing folder. This function also allows us to exclude certain filetypes If you have any other filetypes you'd like to exclude, be sure to add an exclusion to line 21

import json
import boto3
import botocore
import random
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def moveAllFiles(bucket, year):
    count = 0
    dayBuffer = 7
    # For every object in the bucket under the prefix
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix + year + "/"):
        filepath = obj.key
        # If the item isn't a special file
        if "SPECIAL" not in filepath:
            filepathlist = filepath.split("/")
            # if the file's year matches the year we're processing, just a safety check
            if filepathlist[1] == year:
                folder = (filepathlist[2])
                # If the file isn't already processed
                if folder != "Processed":
                    copy_source = {
                        'Bucket': bucket.name,
                        'Key': filepath
                    }
                    today = datetime.now()
                    delta = today - timedelta(days=dayBuffer)
                    if obj.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=None) < delta:
                        try:
                            s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, bucket.name,
                                        "Prefix/" + year + "/Processed/" + filepathlist[2] + "/" + filepathlist[3])
                            print("file " + filepath + " moved to processed folder")
                        except Exception as e:
                            print("error while copying")
                            print(e)
                            raise
                        s3.Object(bucket.name, filepath).delete()
                        print("file " + filepath + " deleted")
                        count = count + 1
                        print(count)
    return count


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        bucket = s3.Bucket(os.environ['BUCKET_NAME'])
        #Change the year variable to handle different subdirectories
        year = "2008"

        count = moveAllFiles(bucket, year)
        print("removed " + str(count) + " files from " + year)
    except Exception as e:
        print("function timed out")
        print(e)
        print("removed " + str(count) + " files from " + year)
        raise
```

For some clarification on why this runs the way it does, in our folders we also have filetypes that should not be moved. This doublechecks that the file in question isn't one of those before copying/deleting. We also need to keep relatively new files, so I added a check to only move stuff older than 1 week. I think I could meet all of my requirements with lifecycle rules but my partner would prefer to run the lifecycle rule on only the processing folder, not the main folders.

So it sounds to me like the main issue here are all of the network calls. What is the correct way to do this? Build a list of everything that needs to be moved then use some kind of promise structure to batch them all out? Boto3 doesn't allow for bulk upload/delete as far as I can tell. I'm also not sue that an entire list will be built within the 15 minute timeframe.

Basically, I'm looking for ways to speed up this process. I'm fine with babysitting it a bit, but the number of processed files per 15 minutes really needs to be 10x'd for this to be a resonable solution

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not run it on an EC2 instead of Lambda?

Comment: @jellycsc There are about 6 hours a day when the job can't run without causing other issues, so we can't just leave it going forever. Also, it'd still take something like 250+ hours to get through everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html), both `copy()` and `meta.client.copy()` result in "a managed transfer which will perform a multipart copy in multiple threads if necessary". That sounds like it is downloading each object to the computer issuing the copy command, and then uploading the object back to S3.

If your objects are less than 5GB in size, then you can use the `copy_from()` method to copy objects from one S3 location to another without having to download and re-upload the object contents, which should dramatically increase the speed of your application.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented this, it looks like the runtime is about the same. Either the meta.client.copy()/copy() methods are smart enough to not do a download, or the bottle neck is somewhere else

Comment: RE, the total number of files processed went up by about 2,000. So a marginal performance gain

Comment: I guess the files are fairly small? This is probably about the best performance you can get out of a single Lambda invocation. I would look into pushing the list of all files that need to be moved into SQS or Kinesis, and spawning many Lambda functions to process that list in paralle.

Comment: Exactly what I'm planning to do Mark

Answer (score 1):

FYI for anyone who stumbles across this in the future. Mark's answer did speed the function up by about 33%, which wasn't sufficient to handle the number of files in S3. To solve this I created a new function that would spawn an instance of "moveAllFiles" for every folder in S3. Basically, instead of having one lambda working on one folder at a time I have 200 lambdas working on 200 folders at once.

This solution may not work for those of you that simply have a massive amount of files in your bucket. First, make sure you can't leverage lifecycle rules. If that's not tenable for some reason, what you could do instead is write a lambda that randomly pulls files from the bucket, evaluates them, and deletes them if they should go. I did not implement this because

1. I didn't want to figure out how to pull random files from S3 at scale
2. I didn't want to deal with the potential concurrency issues (what if a file is deleted by one lambda while another is copying it?)

Both of these are definitely solvable and if you implement it please share your solution!